# Store update doesnot reflect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am following React & Redux. I have actions, reducers working separately. I am managing state more or less properly.

I am trying to create a ui which is having few textboxes and a button(disabled). In text boxes i had added onchange event on which it call a function

```
onChangeTextbox(){

}
```

In this function I do the following thing.
1. I update the state of the redux store.

```
onChangeTextbox(){
  updateStateOfTextBox();
}
```

2.After doing this I look for whether all the text boxes, in the ui, is having something in it. If so I will enable my button to do further operations.

```
onChangeTextbox(){
      updateStateOfTextBox();
      updateStateOfButton();
}
```

Everything is working good except the one thing.
That one thing is as soon as I give the last empty textbox one character, the button is not enabled immediately, and when I give more character the button gets enabled. Similarly vice versa for disabling button.

The problem which I found is that when control complete its job of function `updateStateOfTextBox();` and enters the `updateStateOfButton();` function the state remains same. And again when render() occurs the change in state is reflected then.

I want to fix that issue and I am not getting any way out. Any solution and suggestion to this will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Components update upon prop/state change (excluding shouldComponentUpdate logic). Need to see some more code to see what's wrong.

Comment: No way to help if we at don't at least know *how* you're updating state. Also if you're *querying* state *immediately* after dispatching an action it's probable the state hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: I have not applied any lifecycle method because i donot know how to implement it. I could not provide you with code. The scenario is as it is. If any special care has to be taken pls mention.

Comment: How are you expecting an answer when we can't even see where the problem lies?

Comment: @Dave yes exactly i am doing the same.  can you give any verbal solution to this so that I can get updated state in the next immediate function call?

Comment: @Omri sorry for that

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala No, that isn't how dispatching actions work--you can't query the state immediately after dispatching an action and expect to see it changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to such situation.

```
componentsWillRecieveProps(newProps){

}
```

this method of the life cycle changes the game.

```
componentsWillRecieveProps(newProps){
    newProps.state // this will give you new updated state which your action updated.
    this.props.state // this will give you local or your state
// Here you can update your local state with global state
// And call the other function here as
updateStateOfButton();
}
```

Therefore the solution can be interpreted like

```
onChangeTextbox(){
  updateStateOfTextBox();
}

componentsWillRecieveProps(newProps){
.
.
updateStateOfButton();
}
```